# How to create batch using oData in SAPUI5 but I am able to create single record each time

Tags: odata, sapui5

I am not able to send batch records. But I am able to add single entity each time. I used the following function on submit.
// creating single entry each time.
onSubmitChanges: function() {

```
        var oSelectedVal = this.getView().byId("plmSelect"),
            oSelectedVal = oSelectedVal.getSelectedItem().getKey(),
            oModel = this.getView().getModel(),
            oEntry = {};
        oEntry.MyKeyField1 = oSelectedVal;
        oEntry.MyEntry1  = globalVariable1; // global variable declared to get values
        oEntry.MyEntry2  = globalVariable2;
        oEntry.MyEntry3  = globalVariable3;
        oEntry.MyEntry4  = globalVariable4;

        if (oEntry.MyKeyField1 !== "" && oEntry.MyEntry1 !== "" && oEntry.MyEntry2 !== "") {
            var oContext = oModel.createEntry('/MyEntitySet', {
                properties: oEntry,
                success: function() {
                    MessageToast.show("Create successfuly");
                    // not able to delete/remove after created successfully used the following

                    //oModel.setBindingContext(oContext);
                    //oModel.resetChanges();
                    //aModel.destroyBindingContext();

                    /*oModel.updateBindings({
                        bForceUpdate: true
                    });*/
                    //  oModel.refresh();
                    //oModel.deleteCreatedEntry();
                },
                error: function() {
                    MessageToast.show("Create failed");
                }
            });
            oModel.submitChanges();

            //oModel.refresh();

        } else {
            MessageToast.show("Store Area and Store Description are madatory.");
        }
        this.onUpdateFinished();
    },
```

Comment: Clean your code up before posting here

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What do you want to send as batch? What is not working right now?

Answer (score -2):

Batch is not allowed. You must use deep entity if you wanna send a table.

Comment: Are you sure? Not allowed by what? I've done batch requests in UI5 before.

Comment: This answer is wrong. You can use both, deep insert and batch. They both have their advantages/disavantages.

Comment: Hi Chris,Maybe I am worong but When did you try? Can you share a code ? Because When ı try implement batch method, it wasnt allowed by browser but old standard applications are using it.@ChrisNeve

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is possible because V2.0 oData model supports batch but I have multiple key fields which are passing dynamically on change event of select drop down. I am passing array values for each global variable (oEntry.MyEntry1) but unable to send batch.